# Coverity Connect URL for a snapshot

Tags: coverity

Coverity version - 7.7

In our CI tool, every developer commit, we run `cov-analyze` and `cov-commit-defects` and `cov-commit-defects` outputs the 'Snapshot ID' of the committed version. For instance:

```
****************************************************
[STATUS] 2017-08-23 14:36:38 UTC - Committing 369 summaries...
|0----------25-----------50----------75---------100|
****************************************************
New snapshot ID 19519 added.
Elapsed time: 00:01:22
```

From the home page in Coverity connect, one can manually click on 'All snapshots in project' from the menu and then click on snapshot to see all defects. However, I haven't found that there is a URL to Coverity connect that would take the developer directly to the 'snapshot view'.

Anyone know if there is a way to get a URL for reporting, so that developers can take a look at issues created by their commit in Coverity connect?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to download the latest defects for a specific stream using cov-manage-im as follows:

cov-manage-im --host cim.company.com --port 8080 --user test --password secret --mode defects --show --stream Y --status New

You can also get the Project ID with a given project name using the getProjects API call, and then construct the url for a given view.

Unfortunately, as of now Synopsys does not support viewing of a specific snapshot page "as they are identified via Coverity using an internal format."

https://community.synopsys.com/s/question/0D53400003tGOSeCAO/how-to-create-coverity-url-to-view-specific-snapshot